# C++ - Cannot 'new' an array on unknown size in spite of Braced-List initialization?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-allocation

**Preface:**

I've found nothing around about this issue. The only thing I've found is people dynamically allocating an array without providing any information about the size of said array, like this `int* p = new int[];`

My issue is different:

```
float arr[]{ 1,2,3 };
float* p = new float[]{1, 2, 3};
```

The first line compiles fine, the second one doesn't:

> **Error C3078** Array size must be specified in new expressions

I wonder: why didn't the compiler evaluate the array size from the list-initialization like it did in the first case?

Comment: `std::vector<float> p = {1, 2, 3}` :)

Comment: My question is about a raw pointer holding the memory address of the first element of a dynamically allocated array. If I had wanted to use the STL vector class I'd have already did it.

Comment: We don't like arbitrary constraints here - by making your own life difficult you also make ours difficult!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just sent a question. If it makes your life harder, you can ignore my question.

Comment: @gedamial: You'll get on better here if you lose the confrontational attitude when asking for free help.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If I made a specific question, and you tell me i'm complicating your life, I don't see a reason for you to take my question into account. It was just a tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void* operator new[] (std::size_t size);
```

requires the size explicitly. You can define your own operator to take the initialiser list.

As a commentator said, std::vector is normally the preferred approach but I guess you are interested in the technicalities of the language, which is why you asked.

Comment: By showing me the implementation of the **new operator**, you have perfectly answered my question ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good justification, though. Even the non-array `operator new` takes a size, and that's automatically determined by the compiler. Why can't the compiler deduce it for OP's case? If it can via the "user-defined-parameters-placement-new" (`operator new[](size_t, ...)`) then it looks like an overlook in the Standard?

Answer (score 3):

I think its a perfectly reasonable question, and it just so happens that due to the nature of how the `new` operator is defined this is a limitation on it.

What follows is really contrived, but could work for you if you really wanted to avoid explicitly stating the size of dynamically allocated arrays:

```
template<typename T, T ... args>
T* createArray()
{
    return new T[sizeof...(args)]{args...};
}
```

Then:

```
int* arr = createArray<int, 1, 2, 3>();
```

Comment: Really thanks for showing me the template function alternative ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading Bjarne Stroustrup book "Programming...."
in the Chapter 17, page 597 Bjarne explicitly says:

```
double* p5 = new double[] {0,1,2,3,4}
```

and in paragraph beneath: "... the number of elements can be left out when a set of elements is provided."

So to me seems that this issue is because of bad implementation of compiler, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It just… doesn't. There isn't syntax for it.

You could find a rationale in there somewhere, that dynamic memory is usually populated by dynamic data of a dynamic length (otherwise, unless only because it's huge, why are you using dynamic allocation?) and that static deduction of the size of the requested space is therefore likely to be an edge case seldom used.